# Adding Checkbox to Teamcity configuration parameter specification

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

We know how to add select dropdown to TeamCity parameter configuration, for example:

[image]

Is it possible to add **Checkbox** for TC parameter configuration? If it possible, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible in TeamCity 9 and according to the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Typed+Parameters) it is also possible in 8 as well.

When defining a parameter, simply click the "Spec" button and then select the "Checkbox" option in the "Type" drop down.

[image: Parameter with checkbox]